# Drag and Drop File Uploading

Tags: javascript, html

I am using file uploading in my web application by using the `<input type="file" />` html tag. My feature works well with choosing a file from the file chooser and submitting the file, however now I want to upload a file on drag and drop events i.e. the user drags a file from some location on his computer and when he drops it in a particular section in my web page, the file starts uploading.

Until now I managed to read the files from the drop event by

```
  function drop(evt)
    {
       evt.stopPropogation();
           evt.preventDefault();

       if (containsFiles(evt))
       {
        var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
        var count = files.length;

        // Only call the handler if 1 or more files was dropped.
        if (count > 0)
            // upload files
        }
      }
    }
```

but how can I upload these files? I can't change the value of input type = file for security reasons. So what can I do to pass these files to my servlet?

Comment: have a look at http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

Comment: Or, if you are looking for a well-supported cross-browser library that does all of this for you, have a look at [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  Full disclosure: I maintain Fine Uploader.

Comment: Fine Uploader seems like a fine plug-in! I'm going to dig into it and try to integrate it with my web application. Thanks @Ray Nicholus for your help :)

Comment: @Bernice Sure thing.  Be sure to have a look at the [support page](http://fineuploader.com/support) if you require technical support, uncover a bug, or have an idea/need for a new feature.

Comment: [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) is worth checking out too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) (beware of IE support).

When drop happens you need to create **FormData** object, and append data into it, then **POST** that form to your url. It is **asynchronous** method and will not reload your page.

```
function drop(evt) {
  evt.stopPropogation();
  evt.preventDefault();

  var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    var form = new FormData();

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
      var file = evt.dataTransfer.files[i];
      form.append('image_' + i, file, file.name);
    }

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', '/pathToPostData', true);
    req.onload = function(evt) {
      console.log(req.responseText);
    }
    req.send(form);
  }
}
```

***Beware** that I've tested it only in Chrome and Firefox, IE9 probably will not work but IE10 should, if you test it, let us know please.*

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this answer.  It's a good start.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: I am using this method in single page CMS for API like application, and it works brilliantly. And regarding down-vote. Please who did it, provide info of what and why?

Comment: Thanks @MaksimsMihejevs I tried this just now and it is submitting my data just as I want. The only thing I need now is to use Ajax so that I refresh the page instantly and the users can see that the file has been uploaded.

Comment: You don't really need to refresh page, as your server after upload, can respond with paths to files as well as any extra data you need, then in `.onload` you will receive this data, and can easily using JavaScript update front-end, so it will be much better UX when updated without need of refresh.

Comment: But since I need to display a table with uploaded files and a thumbnail view immediately, I need to refresh the page.

Comment: You can create everything using JS, its still fine. It of course based on your application, and might be it is easier to just refresh if you've got logic already there. But updating small part of page using JS after upload - is more efficient than reloading whole page.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you want something in the likes to [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

I haven't tried it yet, but it's a library that allows for easy drag-and-drop of files to a website that is running it, v3.0 comes without the need to use jQuery.